# Setting the texts in the same line

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-animations

I have this *HTML*:

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="content">
      <h2 class="frame1">Loriam Ipisum</h2>
      <h2 class="frame2">Loriam Ipisumsad</h2>
   </div>
</div>
```

And this *CSS*:

```
body{margin: 0; padding: 0;}

#container{
        width: 100%;        
    top: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;     
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    }

#content{
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    }

#content h2{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    }

#content h2.frame1{
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
    -webkit-animation-name: efeito1;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;      
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
}

#content h2.frame2{
    -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
    -webkit-animation-name: efeito1;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;      
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes efeito1{

   0%{
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;         
}
   50%{         
    opacity: 0.4;
    left: 100px;
    opacity: 0.4;
    left: 200;
}
   100%{                        
    opacity: 0;         
    left: 300px;
    opacity: 0.4;
    }
}
```

What I want to do is: I want both .frames be at the same LINE. SO when I apply the animation, it will happen at the same place, giving a nice effect. I want them to be at the same line, at the same place but without one text be upon the other looking like a mess...
I tried to use the *overflow: Hidden:* but didn't work, the texts stays one above the other...

I want to apply, this effect: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LcwKj/

Any suggestion? Thanks !

Comment: Not so sure what you are trying to do, because what you have now is translating to the right, and the example you provided the link for has nothing to do with that.. Can you explain what you want to achive a bit more?

Comment: Sorry for that @Lawrence. Yes, I want to do exactly what the codepen link does, I was just "playing" with the slide text. On the CodePEN, he has all the texts he wants inside the same div. But it shows one at a time and at the same place, you know? With me, the text are getting one above the other, they are not at the same place, it's going below the previous text. Let me know if I coudn't be clear enough. I tried the let them at the same place with the overflow:hidden, but i didnt work out :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this effect what you are aiming for:

HTML

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="content">
      <h2 class="frame1">Loriam Ipisum</h2>
      <h2 class="frame2">sad</h2>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body{margin: 0; padding: 0;}

#container{
        width: 100%;        
    top: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;     
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    }

#content{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    }

#content h2{
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    }

#content h2.frame1{
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
    -webkit-animation-name: efeito1;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;      
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
    opacity:0;
}

#content h2.frame2{
    -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
    -webkit-animation-name: efeito1;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;      
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
    opacity:0;
    position:absolute;
}

@-webkit-keyframes efeito1{

   0%{
    opacity: 0;
    }
   100%{                        
    opacity: 100;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Lawrence, could you explain to me, please? What was I doing wrong to not show the text at the same line with the overflow ?

Comment: You had the `left` attribute defined differently for those two elements. Also, for `50%` transition, you had two different `left` attributes defined.

Comment: Sorry, but it still the same... I can see only the first frame effect. the other is hiden below the first. It's like the overflow:hidden isn't working...

Comment: The `width` of your `#content` is to small. The two strings you use are too wide, and the second frame gets moved below. You can see this if you set the `height` of the `#content` to 200px for example. To solve this, i would suggest to use the `width:100%` for the `#content`. I will correct my answer to include this. If you want to make it work with your `width` you need to add `position:absolute;` to the `frame2`. This might be the best solution for you.

Comment: the width I was using is just an example... PLeae, feel free to make your answer with your own sizes... Thanks for helping me !

Comment: Is it working when you set the `position:absolute;` for the `frame2`?

Comment: You forgot to update the jsfiddle... It's the same I sent you '-'

Comment: With your updated answer. It's one beside the other. BUt I'd like it to stay at the same place... But one above the other, so the effects would look like the codepen link.

Comment: You need to tweak the opacity of course, but that is the basic idea.

Comment: Amazing, you did the trick ! You're awesome. Thanks a bunch Lawrence!!

Comment: No problem, enjoy! :)